# Find ampersend & in a string (bash)

Tags: string, bash, escaping

I had this
string="dontcare noone &11111-&1111-&C00 noone"

and I had to extract the substring &11111-&1111-&C00 
from the  first & to the first blank

I've tried some index and some sed without any luck.

Someone has some great advice?

Comment: Are you looking to extract this string in particular or any string of the form &number-&number-&whatever ?

Comment: The only thing sure in the string is that start with & and ending with a blank. I've tried to use escaping char without reach my goal.. Now I go try the solution of larsks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use bash's string manipulation capabilities:

```
string="dontcare noone &11111-&1111-&C00 noone"

# remove everything up to the first "&"
string="&${string#*&}"

# remove everything from the end to the earliest blank
string="${string%% *}"

# ta da!
echo $string
&11111-&1111-&C00
```

Comment: thx! it work perfectly.  
$string="dontcare noone &11111-&1111-&C00 noone"  $stringa="&${string#*\&}" $ stringb="${stringa%% *}"  
$echo $stringb  
&11111-&1111-&C00  
@OdayMansour

Comment: I was in need also of first part of string... I do this way  
eval $(echo "$string" | awk '{split($0,SPLIT," \&"); print "ONE=\""SPLIT[1]"\"";print "TWO=\"&"SPLIT[2]"\""}') and  three="${TWO%% *}"

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo "dontcare noone &11111-&1111-&C00 noone" | grep -o '&[^ ]*'
&11111-&1111-&C00
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the "to the first blank" condition.

Comment: @dbaupp: sorry, didn't note that; fixed now; thank you for the remark!

Answer (score 0):

Bash regular expressions will work as well:

```
[[ $string =~ (&[[:alnum:]]+-?)+ ]]; echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
```

The regex matches one or more groups, where a group is an ampersand followed by one or more letters/numbers and an optional final hyphen. If the match is successful (i.e., the [[ ]] command has exist status 0), then the first element of the array `BASH_REMATCH` contains the text from `string` that matched the regex.

Answer (score -1):

Use grep.

```
echo "dontcare noone &11111-&1111-&C00 noone" > somefile.txt

grep somefile.txt -e "&" | cut -d " " > someotherfile.txt
```

grep will basically "cat" the output and search for the pattern, instantiated with -e , and pull the string with &

The > will push the output into a file that you already have, or simply name there, and it'll create it.

You can then overwrite the somefile.txt anytime you want, or append strings.

To be honest, there's a multitude of ways to do this; grep is one of the better options when searching for specific strings, but even that being said, you can already tell in this question there's many, many ways to grep things.

Pipes, | ; and's,  && , and many other options, will provide you with ways to combine grep with other commands to get the exact output you are searching for.

I also see you want it to the first "blank space", which I have just added to the top code.  Using "cut" and a delimeter of " ", you can extract only data after spaces.  Using cut's field settings, it's possible to switch what's being pulled.

Comment: `somefile.txt` will have just one line, and grep will ouput that entire line.

Comment: Right, using somefile.txt as a dummy.  Grep will output the entire line starting at the first space, unless you give it field delimeter's too; but I'm not about to throw him the entire code, simply point him in the correct direction so he can modify it himself.

Google could've provided an answer to his question, but in fairness I decided to give him an explanation and some ideas to further his own progress.  This is by no means a paradisaical code; but one to push constructive flow.  Thought that's what this site was about.

Comment: I agree. I'm really in "point him in the correct direction so he can modify it himself" thx for your explanation and your time.